# How to view the existing images in WinEdt for Menus? (Not ToolBar)

Tags: winedt, customize

How to view the existing images in WinEdt for Menus? (Not ToolBar)

How can you see the existing images available for menus, to type in IMAGE="....."

[image]

Comment: See in the winedt help the section about Image Resources.

Comment: ok, Double clicking in IMAGE word, open the Special Dialog

Comment: @UlrikeFischer do you know how to add images?.